# Github to salesforce deployment

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, version-control, github, dockercloud

I need to find a way to deploy code from GitHub to salesforce using Docker Cloud or Docker because my client requested it. I needed senior's suggestions on deployment from GitHub to to salesforce with [docker](https://www.docker.com/) and i found way to do it with BitBucket [here](https://www.cloudinit.nz/single-post/2016/11/25/Automated-Salesforce-Deployments-with-BitBucket-Pipelines) but didn't find with GitHub or at least is it possible at the current moment.

Comment: Please don't "ask" the same question more than once. If clarification is requested,, or you have more to add, please edit your question instead,

Comment: @sfdcfox i didnt done it intentionally, when i submitted question initially it was blocked by my company internet policy because it has keyword "GitHub" and i cant see that question even to delete it., i'm trying close it by mobile app, Any how please give your ideas for my question.